# how can I show a loading icon for each loading image using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, loading

I want to show a spinner in the place of each image that is still loading using jQuery.  Is this too much animation? Total loading would only be 8 images.  Should I just use a spinner that goes for the whole page until all up to 8 are loaded even if 3 of them are fully loaded and ready to go already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A spinner is not a bad idea for all eight images.  You don't have to worry about it as much because it's the same image (and presumably a small one).  The browser will load it once and use a cached version for the other seven.  I suggest using the loading image as the background image (CSS) for the image containers.  That way, once it's loaded, the background image is just covered and you don't need to worry about processing complete loads for each image.

Comment: If I use a loading image as a background image, it will not animate though, right?  It would have to be a spinner attached to a load() with success: spinner removal.

Comment: @TravisJ no, it would work still.  You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ejV2q/show.  Note that the second frame is there just to show what it would look like loading in case you miss it from the first one.  Source here: http://jsfiddle.net/ejV2q/

Comment: Joseph: I realized after I commented that you were talking about an animated .gif which I actually implemented in the same fashion you indicated in your jsfiddle.  Worked great, it was a good suggestion! Thanks